# No keyboard input from GLUT while mouse is moving (In OS X)

Tags: macos, opengl, keyboard, glut

So I just built an OpenGL application on a Mac for the first time. I'm using GLUT to get keyboard input. The trouble is, I've discovered that if I'm moving the mouse at the same time I push a button on the keyboard, my keyboard function doesn't get called! If I push a button when the mouse isn't moving, it gets called just fine. The same goes for my keyUp function. Why could this be?

I'm also having trouble with the mouse motionFunc - it seems to not be getting called every frame and lead to choppy mouse input ...

Comment: Which GLUT [implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Utility_Toolkit#Implementations)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you provide a code sample? It sounds like a bug in your event handling code.

That said, GLUT is no longer developed and you should not be using it. There are numerous better alternatives, the most popular being [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/). Others include [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/) and [SFML](http://sfml-dev.org/), and you can even use [Qt](http://doc.trolltech.com/3.3/qglwidget.html).

Comment: That's good to know. I'm using the GLUT framework that came with XCode. I found that calling glutWarpPointer on a mouse move (to do a freelook) is what was causing the keyboard input to not go through. I'll look at these others. Thanks!